# Javascript Modal gallery всплывает ненужное окно

Tags: javascript, html, css, modal

Возникла проблема просмотром "картинок" в модальном окне.При нажати на кнопки `next or prev` сплывает ненужный блок.Уже второй день  не получается решить проблему .Помогите найти ошибку. заранее спасибо.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#div'),
  caption = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-content .modal-caption'),
  modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
  next = document.getElementById('next'),
  prev = document.getElementById('prev'),
  index = 0;



for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {

  divs[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {

  for (var i = 0; i < caption.length; i++) {
    caption[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
    if (divs[j] == this) {
      modal.style.display = "block";
      caption[j].style.display = "block";
      break;
    }
  }

}



next.addEventListener('click', function() {

  caption[index].style.display = "none";
  index++;
  if (index >= caption.length) {
    index = 0;
  }

  caption[index].style.display = "block";

});

prev.addEventListener('click', function() {

  caption[index].style.display = "none";
  index--;
  if (index < 0) {
    index = caption.length - 1;
  }

  caption[index].style.display = "block";

});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

p{cursor:pointer;}

div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
}

#modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: none;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.modal-content {
  width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 25%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.modal-content>.modal-caption {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

#close {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3em;
  right: 3em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span#prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  right: 10%;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="div"><p>ImageOne</p></div>
<div id="div"><p>ImageTwo</p></div>
<div id="div"><p>ImageThree</p></div>
<div id="div"><p>ImageFour</p></div>
<div id="div"><p>ImageFive</p></div>


<div id="modal">
  <span id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display='none';">Close</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-caption">
      <h1>ImageOne</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-caption">
      <h1>ImageTwo</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-caption">
      <h1>ImageThree</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-caption">
      <h1>ImageFour</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-caption">
      <h1>ImageFive</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span id="next"><</span>
  <span id="prev">></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если заменить вашу строку:

```
  <span id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display='none';">Close</span>
```

вот так:

```
  <span id="close" onclick="document.getElementById('modal').style.display='none';index = 0;">Close</span>
```

будет как надо?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ очень помогло . Можете  обяснить разницу в коде.

Comment: Там видно, что добавил строку: index = 0; т.е. при нажатии на "Close" у Вас не обнулялось значение и новый старт происходил со старыми данными. Удачи.